# How fast is it to call len() on a slice?

Tags: go

I am wondering how fast is it to access `len()` of a slice. If I need to use the length of a slice for a few time, is it worthwhile to store it to an `int` variable? Or calling `len()` will be optimized as if an int variable is accessed? (In such case, there is no need to store the length of a variable by the user.) Thanks.

Comment: Length is already an integer property of a slice: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: But will the function call `len()` be optimized away?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - all it does is read an int. That's about as optimized as it gets. Storing it in a variable would be no change; you'd be reading an int just like `len` does.

Comment: My question is whether the function call of `len()` actually appears in the compile binary code.

Comment: What does it mean for "`len()` to appear in the compile binary code"? The corresponding instructions must be in the binary for it to work. Whether that means it's an inlined "function" or a compiler construct is really just irrelevant details about the implementation. It all boils down to some MOV instructions regardless of what you call it.

Comment: I mean whether `len()` is inlined or not.

Comment: The builtin len() is function syntax for several operations known to the compiler.  For slice arguments, the operation is slice length read.  There is no runtime function for reading the length field.

Comment: * "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth* I suggest [profiling on your code](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs). `len()` will hardly be something which will be a culprit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding:

You can regard `slice` as a `struct`,of which `length` is a member.

The only thing function `len()` does is to read that member of `type slice struct`,thus there is no need to worry about its performance---it's as fast as reading the `length int` you create by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

All of build-in functions not actually functions. It might be bunch of another functions or just one asm instruction (as for this case).

Here's slice struct:

```golang
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr // sizeof(uintptr) = 8 byte
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}
```

To get len of slice, we should to get offset from pointer of slice.
Go-idiomatic variant looks like following:

```golang
*(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(pointer_to_slice) + 8))
```

As you can see, output goasm code of len(b) equals one instruction:
https://godbolt.org/z/z0PtMe

```golang
var b1 = []byte{1, 2, 3}
var b2 = []byte{4, 5, 6}

func main() {
   l1 := len(b1)

   if len(b2) == l1 {
       println(l1)
   } else {
       println(len(b2))
   }
}
```

`l1 := len(b1)`

=

`movq    "".b1+8(SB), AX // ax == l1`

but,  for `len(b2) == l1` compiler creates additional variable:

`movq    "".b2+8(SB), CX // cx == len(b2) in "if" statement`

So, we can conclude that creating new variable for length does not affect performance.